# Asynchronous webservices without WS-Addressing

Tags: java, web-services

In Java, can you call a webservice asynchronously *without pooling for a response* (using a callback pattern instead) if the webservice does not use WS-Addressing ?

Answer (score 1):

WS-Addressing is the defined way in the **SOAP** specification that supports asynchronous calls with callback. It *is* the callback feature, which is supported by JAX-WS 2.0 (for details check my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23860503/3231778)).

The answer to your question is yes, you *can* do it using Java. However, *if the webservice does not use WS-Addressing* then you will have to implement your client to be compliant to the server callback mechanism, which I assume would be proprietary or other pattern/library available.

Using the WS-Addressing feature as a reference for your custom solution, you would have to send the callback information (protocol, address, function, etc) along with the message to the Web Service server, which later would notify your application about the conclusion or even send the results.