# RUN code after sending SOAP response in java

Tags: java, soap, web, service

My web service get a SOAP request from user. After doing all the stuff in service could I send back the user response and then run some code ?

Actually I want to log the output of my service. If I run the code that logs the output and if that logging service fails, I could not send back any response due to that error.

IS there a way that I send user response of my service and then run logging service after that ?

I tried close method of SOAP handler but it runs before my service has returned response.

Comment: How do you make your web service: is it Spring or JEE or something else?

Comment: Can you show some code. There are multiple approaches to do this from AOP, interceptors, Dynamic proxies, ... A lot of frameworks offer a solution for this, as it is far from an uncommon need.

Comment: Can I use handleResponse() of SOAP Handler ?

Comment: Web service is J2EE web service using @WebService. Sorry I am a bit naive in this.

Comment: Code is very large. The main idea is like this. Get SOAP request, do something, log any error of my web service. return response (it automatically returns after service ends).  I just want to do logging after user gets my SOAP response (end of service). I read on ORACLE interceptors that "When the handleResponse() method of the first handler in the handler chain executes, WebLogic server returns the final SOAP message response to the client application that invoked the Web Service."

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to find a callback (http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/understanding-callbacks-with-java.html) you can hook into after the http response has been accepted back from the server.

See here for a similar question: [SOAP web service callback architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290984/soap-web-service-callback-architecture) that was answered.

Answer (score 0):

You should use callback function to sure that responsing is finished

Answer (score 0):

Use try-catch to control the errors in your code. For your case you can control if your logging service fails or not and send the response to user.

[Exceptions try](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

If you want to use something more complex you can use an async approach using queues or events.

Answer (score 0):

in JEE you can use "@Asynchronous" annotation for the method that need to log. It will run asynchronously, so it will not block the return of the webservice.

If you need the result of that method, you will need manage to store the reference of the Future, for example in a singleton, then get the esult in a second  Webservice call.