# Soap request to a client in gSoap

Tags: c++, web-services, soap, server, gsoap

I am using gSoap and I have a similar problem. I have to program a server. The client should send a subscription request (that would include its URL). The server stores this information, and replies to the client. This is done. However, how does the server send the notifications to the client when the events take place?
I have written the rest of the services, where the server responses the requests of the client. But I have no idea about how to do the rest of the program.

I would need to create three kinds of functions:
1) A method for the client to to subscribe:

```
int __ns1__SubscribeToEventNotifications(
    struct soap* p_soap,
    _ns1__SubscribeToEventNotifications *ns1__SubscribeToEventNotifications,
    _ns1__SubscribeToEventNotificationsResponse,
    &ns1__SubscribeToEventNotificationsResponse
);
```

2) A method for the server to notify an enevent to the subscribed clients:

```
int __ns1__NotifyEventHappened(
    struct soap* p_soap,
    _ns1__EventHappened *ns1__EventHappened,
    _ns1__EventHappenedResponse &ns1__NotifyEventHappenedResponse
);
```

3) A method for the client to unsubscribe:

```
int __ns1__UnsubscribeFromEventNotifications(
     struct soap* p_soap,
     _ns1__UnsubscribeFromEventNotifications,
     *ns1__UnsubscribeFromEventNotifications,
     _ns1__UnsubscribeFromEventNotificationsResponse,
     &ns1__UnsubscribeFromEventNotificationssResponse
);
```

In [SOAP web service callback architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290984/soap-web-service-callback-architecture/40910750?noredirect=1#comment69034334_40910750), Glen Best wrote:

> "You can push the notification from the server to the client if you know the client's SOAP endpoint address. The client can transfer it's SOAP endpoint address within original SOAP request payload. Sometime later the server can send a SOAP request to the client."

How is this request from server to client done?

Thanks in advance, David Marcos

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited the question.
 Thanks.